# How to add a text search dialog in Android Studio Java/XMl app?

Tags: android

How to add a text search dialog in Android Studio Java/XMl app? Developing a book-type app. Need to enable users to search any word in the text-view pages displaying to them. Thank you.

Comment: where are your efforts ?

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve this using custom views inside an alert dialog. Below is the sample code.

```
AlertDialog.Builder dialog = new AlertDialog.Builder(cont);
    dialog.setIcon(R.drawable.ic_launcher);
    dialog.setTitle("AlertDialog with EditText");
    dialog.setCancelable(false);
    LayoutInflater layoutInflater = LayoutInflater.from(cont);
    final View textEntryView = layoutInflater.inflate(
            R.layout.alert_dialog_text_entry, null);
    dialog.setView(textEntryView);
    dialog.setPositiveButton("Ok", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
            Dialog inDialog = (Dialog) dialog;
            EditText edt = (EditText) inDialog.findViewById(R.id.editText1);
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                    edt.getText().toString() + "\n Ok Clicked",
                    Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    });

    dialog.setNegativeButton("Cancel",
            new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {

                @Override
                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                            "Cancel Clicked", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }
            });

    dialog.show();
```

For source check [here](http://www.skholingua.com/android-basic/advance-topics/alert-dialog-toast)